# why my addEventListner does not work as onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
```

I want to toggle between myFunction1 and myFunction2 using function looped with click event

```
<p id="demo">Click me.</p>
    <p id="demo1">Click me.</p>
```

In this script I used addeventlistner function

```
    <script>
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", myFunction1);

function myFunction1() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
  document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click",myFunction2);
}
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME2!";
  document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click",myFunction1);
}

document.getElementById("demo1").addEventListener("click",myFunction3);

function myFunction3() {
   document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME3!";
  document.getElementById("demo1").onclick = function(){myFunction4()};
}
function myFunction4() {
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME4!";
  document.getElementById("demo1").onclick =function(){myFunction3};
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Doesn't work how? What happens?

Comment: Your edit adds more functions, but doesn't answer the question above: What about your code doesn't work as expected? (Did I guess right in my answer that the problem is you were expecting them to toggle, and instead they just add together and call both functions?)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to toggle between the two, you need to use `removeEventListener` to remove the previous handler; otherwise, you just end up with both attached. See `***` lines:

```
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", myFunction1);
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
  document.getElementById("demo").removeEventListener("click",myFunction1); // ***
  document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click",myFunction2);
}
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME2!";
  document.getElementById("demo").removeEventListener("click",myFunction2); // ***
  document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click",myFunction1);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", myFunction1);
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
  document.getElementById("demo").removeEventListener("click",myFunction1); // ***
  document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click",myFunction2);
}
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME2!";
  document.getElementById("demo").removeEventListener("click",myFunction2); // ***
  document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click",myFunction1);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="demo">Click Me</button>
```

A simpler solution, though, might be to use a flag and call the appropriate function based on the flag:

```
let flag = false;
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    flag = !flag;
    (flag ? myFunction1 : myFunction2)(event);
});
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME2!";
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let flag = false;
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    flag = !flag;
    (flag ? myFunction1 : myFunction2)(event);
});
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME2!";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="demo">Click Me</button>
```

This bit:

```
(flag ? myFunction1 : myFunction2)(event);
```

is basically:

```
if (flag) {
    myFunction1(event);
} else {
    myFunction2(event);
}
```